# How to Comparison between 2 groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tasked with given Data and 3 table; `Sales`, `Dates` and `Stores` so far I have couple choosen KPI's to answer given Business questions, however I am stuck with efficiency of this query also I need couple feedback.

My question is In Store table there is **store_group** inside of that column there is **store_group** [A] AND [B] I want to sort this as sum of store_group A and store_group B so that I can make another calculation such as difference between A and B to assume A/B successful in Sales, also in my query I made a logical calculation that finds growth(next year growth) per previous column data-*NextYearGrowth depending on previous date*- I will add percentage to it so it will be better?

I appreciate feedbacks and suggestions

DDL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dates4](
    [date_id] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [calendar_month] [int] NOT NULL,
    [year] [int] NOT NULL,
    [iso_week] [int] NOT NULL,
    [iso_period] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dates4] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [date_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sales](
    [store_id] [int] NULL,
    [date_id] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [baskets] [int] NULL,
    [spend] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[store](
    [store_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [store_group] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_store] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [store_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

QUERY THAT needs to be **9x column 9x row**

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    (SELECT top 1 AVG(store_id) FROM store WHERE store_group = 'A' ) as SumStore_A ,
    Sl.baskets,
    SL.spend -LAG (SL.spend) OVER (ORDER BY Calendar_Month ASC) AS SpendGrowth,
    LEAD (SL.spend, 12) OVER (ORDER BY DS.date_id ASC) AS NextYearGrowth,
    CASE 
        WHEN SL.spend >= 1000 AND SL.spend <= 5000  THEN 'Low'
        WHEN SL.spend >= 5000 AND sl.spend <= 15000 THEN 'Moderate'
        ELSE 'High'
        END as SpendGroups,
    ST.store_group,
     DS.date_id,
    DS.calendar_month,
    DS.iso_week,
    DS.iso_period
FROM sales SL
    INNER JOIN store ST 
        on ST.store_id = SL.store_id
    INNER JOIN dates4 DS
        on ds.date_id = SL.date_id
    GROUP BY 
    SL.store_id,
    Sl.baskets,
     CASE 
        WHEN SL.spend >= 1000 AND SL.spend <= 5000  THEN 'Low'
        WHEN SL.spend >= 5000 AND sl.spend <= 15000 THEN 'Moderate'
        ELSE 'High'
        END,
        SL.spend,
        DS.calendar_month,
        DS.iso_period,
        DS.date_id,
        ST.store_group,
        DS.iso_week
```

output
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULZDC.png) there you can see my data, and store_group data thats what I need to sort something like:

```
|Store A | Store B| 
Sum(Data) Sum(Data)
```

PS. I need to work on my code, any other suggestions would be amazing. I was thinking inside of INNER JOIN using calculations such as SUM store_group in Store Table(nested query inside inner join) that will be much easy to execute if we have huge data and 1 select statement?

Comment: I have removed the conflicting database tags. PLease dont spam tags, they are designed to gather the correct audience for your question and not to gather an angry mod. PLease add back ONLY the relevant DBMS tag that you are actually using

Comment: Considering the syntax of the DDL statements, this appears to be SQL Server not MySQL.

Comment: @Larnu yeah it was in suggestion of tags, so I add it. My bad

Comment: Use of DISTINCT is often a kludge to fix a logical error in a query. Always schema-qualify your object (i.e., table) names. Always use the appropriate alias when referencing EVERY column. Terminate every statement. Use of TOP with an aggregate IS logical nonsense. I could go on but you have a lot to improve and that is beyond the purpose of SO.

Comment: Last comment - a **calendar** is for DATES, not datetimes. Sloppy design leads to sloppy code and adds risk that someone accidentally provides an unexpected time component for any date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find a way, way better.

```
SELECT M.calendar_month,
            totalbasketsA,
            totalspendA, 
            totalspendA/totalbasketsA AS AVgBasketA,
            totalbasketsB,
            totalspendB, 
            totalspendB/totalbasketsB AS AVgBasketB,
            basketDiff,
            spenddiff FROM 
            (SELECT T1.calendar_month,T1.totalbasketsA,T1.totalspendA,t2.totalbasketsB,t2.totalspendB, T1.totalbasketsA - T2.totalbasketsB AS basketDiff, T1.totalspendA-t2.totalspendB AS spenddiff FROM 
                    (SELECT SUM(spend) totalspendA, SUM(baskets) totalbasketsA, store_group, calendar_month from sales S1
                            INNER JOIN store S2 ON S1.store_id=S2.store_id
                            INNER JOIN dates4 S3 ON S3.date_id= S1.date_id
                                WHERE store_group='A'
                    GROUP BY store_group,calendar_month )  AS T1
     -- T1 for store A result set that is grouped by store_group and calendar_month
                        INNER JOIN 
     
      
                (SELECT SUM(spend) totalspendB, SUM(baskets) totalbasketsB, store_group, calendar_month from sales S1
                        INNER JOIN store S2 ON S1.store_id=S2.store_id
                        INNER JOIN dates4 S3 ON S3.date_id= S1.date_id
                            WHERE store_group='B'
                    GROUP BY store_group,calendar_month )   AS T2 ON T1.calendar_month = T2.calendar_month  ) M
```